# How to submit multiple arrays based on selected checkboxes?

Tags: php, html, arrays, checkbox, submit

I have a list of items and I am selecting some of them but when I submit the form I need to have 3 arrays with different values submitted to PHP, so the following three arrays: **Device id, Client comment and Manufacturer comment**.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="devices[<?php echo $cases["dev_comment"]; ?>][<?php echo $cases["manuf_comment"]; ?>]" value="<?php echo $cases["Dev_Id"] ?>">
```

and in php I am doing:

```
$devices_selected = $_POST['devices'];
```

print :

```
Array (
    [comment 1 for IMEI no. 277745.5] => Array (
        [manuf comment for dev 1] => 1298
    )
    [comment 2 for IMEI no.576] => Array (
        [0] => 1318
    )
)
```

It doesnt look correct, I dont even know how to access each value of 3 arrays this way.

Comment: Could you maybe show some values of what you would LIKE it to be? Then it would help us, help you towards the right direction.

Comment: I am wondering *why* you would want to do this. If this is database related, then I would suggest you use another method. But to (try and) answer what you're asking, you could use a `foreach` on it and use the key value(s).

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner  I need the array like that because I need to push all three arrays with the selected values at the same time. How else can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

In your code the `name` attribute is as

`name="devices[<?php echo $cases["dev_comment"]; ?>][<?php echo $cases["manuf_comment"]; ?>]"`

This creates a multidimensional array as with keys

Just to explain the whole thing lets have a look at an example

```
<input type="text" name="name['hello']['world']">
```

If your `name` attribute is set like this we would get an array as

```
Array
(
    [name] => Array
        (
            ['hello'] => Array
                (
                    ['world'] => John
                )

        )

)
```

As we can see it creates an multi-dimensional array with the key as `hello` and second as `world`.

So doing this in your code your are making your code a bit more complicated you can just mention in your code `name` as `name = devices`.

Comment: that's the point, I need the array like that because I need to push all three arrays with the selected values at the same time. How else can I do that?

Comment: I think you just need `name[]` this will get all the values and create one array.